# I am having difficulty getting Ajax to send a post request with a django form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django-forms

I am trying to build a web app using django. I want to show a form where the user answers a question. The form displays correctly, and I am able to submit correctly without ajax. I want the form data to post without refreshing the page. I am new to web development, and I am having a hard time finding answers to my specific questions. When I click submit the form doesn't submit through django (which is intended), but my development server doesn't receive a post request. Also I keep getting an error
"Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at xb (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:formatted:3481)"

html:

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
HOSTED VIDEO
  {{form1.ch}}
  {% csrf_token %}


<script>
$(document).on("submit","#form1",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
 const csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;
$.ajax({
  headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
  type:"POST",
  url: "/hlg/",
  data: {'form':form1},
  success: alert('yay')
 })
 });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi , what is `form1` here ?  Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6960586/10606400) might help .

Comment: That link that you sent answered my question, THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: If you repost your comment as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi, you can answer your own question :)